# Eclipse Plugin: what property attribut for testing name of subversion resources

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins, properties

I'm writing a plugin. To start it, the menu entry is displayed when doing a rightclick on a project in SVN-Plugin-View. By using "org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.repository.RepositoriesView" as locationURI inside the plugin.xml my menu entry is visible, as I wanted.
But now I want to make it visible under special conditions. I don't find out, what property I can use to test the name of the Project.

I already did something similar inside Eclipse with

```
<command...
    <visible when>
       <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
         <iterate ifEmpty="false">
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="Test_*"/>
            </adapt>
         </iterate>
       </with>
    </visibleWhen>
</command>
```

Now I use

but I don't find out what to use as test property
Like in my working (without SVN) example I tried
<test property="org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.name" value="Test_*/>"
But it did not work. The menu entry was not visible for SVN-Projects with names starting with "Test_"

Comment: You would have to look at the subversion plug-ins to see what property testers they define (if any). Look for the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point in the plugin.xml of the plug-ins.

Comment: Thank you very much, Greg. I haven't found a plugin.xml file after extracting the jar of the plugin. In my own plugins its always on top level with META-INF..

Comment: Plug-ins don't have to have a plugin.xml if they are not using any extensions. If there isn't one then the plug-in doesn't define any properties testers and there is nothing you can test.